# How to perform channel wise convolution

Tags: python, pytorch, conv1d

I have an input tensor of shape (10,3,4,6). The 6 is the channel dimension. If I need to perform convolution (1D and 2D both) channel-wise ( each channel should have different weights and bias) using Pytorch, how can I implement it?

Please give me an example code

Answer (score 0):

depth-wise convolution is what you need:

```py
import torch
from torch import nn
input = torch.randn(10,3,4,6)
# change the channel dimension as conv in torch need BxCxHxW
input = input.permute(0, 3, 1, 2).contiguous() 
# set the group as the number of channels
conv = nn.Conv2d(6, 6, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, groups=6)
print(conv(input))
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In this case, when the model is training, at each epoch, is  the same group of kernels applied to the given channel?

Comment: Yeah, as the number of groups equals the number of channels, every channel has a different kernel.